How to Interpret Reconstruction Error for Anomaly Detection with Autoencoders?
I have an autoencoder based on a neural network. This model was trained using SCADA data. I got decent results in anomaly detection, with around 85% in the main metrics (recall, accuracy, precision, and F1 score).
When I started analyzing the reconstruction error around the anomaly period, I observed that the parameters contributing the most to the anomaly were not necessarily related to its cause.
The "id" parameter contributed around 50-60% to the reconstruction error (RE), while the parameter that should be correlated with the anomaly contributed only 10% to the RE. The "other" parameter represents the sum of all parameters that are not "id". The graph below shows this behavior:

This behavior occurred in other anomalies, not just in this dataset but in others as well. These datasets are considerably large, with around 100 parameters in the smallest and 600 in the largest, each with over 5 years of data and a 10-minute granularity. Therefore, I don't believe it's due to a lack of data.
I tried removing the "id" parameter, but this significantly affected the main metrics, bringing them down to around 50-60%.
Regarding the "id" parameter, it has a strong correlation with time as a positive, monotonic series.
Even though the model is detecting anomalies well, does this behavior make it unreliable? One possible explanation I found is that, given the input and its specific conditions, the autoencoder predicts a different "id"/time for the input. I think it’s possible that the model has implicitly learned the temporal characteristics of the turbine’s operation. As a result, it determines that the given conditions do not align with the expected temporal patterns.
Does this explanation seem reasonable? I accept suggestions also to improve the model.
I validated the model with different datasets, tried refining the autoencoder with optuna hyperparameter optimization and tried different data treatments. All the tentatives lead to the same result.
